# Web font that supports some basic music symbols

Tags: fonts, webfonts

I am working on a web page that displays some music note names such as "B", "Bb" (B flat), or C# (C sharp). For a better readability I would prefer to display the correct flat and sharp symbols.

It seems that the standard sans-serif fonts such as Arial or Helvetica do not support these symbols, which leads me to the conclusion that I need to find a web font that looks similar to the widespread sans-serifs (Arial, Helvetica) and in addition has these two symbols.

Q1: Do you know of any such web font?

Q2: Or was I completely mistaken and the Arial and Helvetica actually do support musical notation symbols, and they happen to be in the same position for both of these fonts?

Comment: Ascii 225 is ß but for sharp I'm afraid you will have to use classic #

Comment: To the one who voted for closing: I first posted this on UX, and they considered it offtopic and told me to post here.

Comment: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266f/fontsupport.htm and http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/266d/fontsupport.htm may help?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why the people on UX think font suggestions are a programming question, but I think they're probably wrong.

Comment: As I stated on UX, it is not on-topic there. I never said it was on-topic here, either, however.

Comment: @ThomasHaratyk - Actually, 223 is that character. However, that isn't the same as the "flat" character anyways.

Comment: My UX question was migrated to graphic design: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/web-font-that-supports-some-basic-music-symbols and seems to be accepted there :-) I voted for closing this question here.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using CSS3 to allows the programmer to use custom fonts safely, you could just superscript or subscript a 'b' or a '#'. People would most likely get your point.

Answer (score 0):

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7058/web-font-that-supports-some-basic-music-symbols

This probably **is** a UX question, because web-fonts like this won't be accessible. If you don't like b or # then you might use images inline with alt-text of "flat" or "sharp" in order that screen-readers will cope.

If you simply use a random character from a music web font (say the flat is at the postion where M is normally), screen-readers could read A-flat as AM -- either as the word *am* or two letters *A M* -- which isn't good. The same goes for using Ab or C#: screen-readers won't necessarily read out what the context requires.

Comment: Thank's Andrew. Your answer is *partially* helpful: I kind of like the idea with the images. For the part about the webfont, you probably got me wrong. I've voted to close this question and answered on graphicdesign.

Answer (score 0):

As for Q1, a font that IMO shows adequate flat and sharp symbols is Arial Unicode MS:
[image: Flat-Sharp-Symbols]

It's also used on this Website:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_names_and_symbols_(popular_music)

Unfortunately this font is 22 MB in size which is a bit large just for those symbols.